# Grid component alignment

Tags: material-ui

I created a basic grid layout that contains three items.

```
 import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
 import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
 import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';

function Layout(props) {

return (
    <Grid container spacing={24}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Paper square  ><img src="wind/images.jpg"/></Paper>
            <Paper square  ><img src="wind/images.jpg"/></Paper>
            <Paper square  ><img src="wind/images.jpg"/></Paper>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
);
```

I notice that there is a small space on the right side.

How can I equally align the content on the page so there will be no space on the edge of the screen?

Thank you

Comment: A [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing the current behavior you are seeing would be helpful.

Comment: https://726v017oz1.codesandbox.io/

Comment: This is the problem:https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/7466